# How come ArrayDataProvider is best used for big array but is less efficient yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a class which extends from `yii\rest\Controller`, under this class is a function which returns an instance of `ArrayDataProvider` in JSON format.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $user = User::find();

    return $this->query($user->asArray()->all(), true);
}

protected function query($qry, $paginate=false)
{
    $this->serializer['preserveKeys'] = false;

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $qry,
    ]);

    if ($paginate) {
        $dataProvider->setPagination(['pageSize' => 20]);
    } else {
        $dataProvider->setPagination(false);
    }

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Assuming that the array returned is composed of 130k items (from `actionIndex`). Do everytime I hit this API with a `page` parameter on it, the `ArrayDataProvider` will process the 130k records and sliced it all over again?

Can someone tell what's the exact behavior an `ArrayDataProvider` is running? Is there any efficient way of handling such big array? What's the perks of using this as opposed with other providers?

Thank you!

Comment: From the docs (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html): Note: Compared to Active Data Provider and SQL Data Provider, array data provider is less efficient because it requires loading all data into the memory.
I guess is it better to handle pagination in your query rather than in such a big array.

Comment: Thanks, I decided not to use an `ActiveDataProvider` to handle the pagination because first of all my query is so complicated, so I didn't want to make the handling of SQL cumbersome.